# TSQL Combinar tablas con datos completos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de combinar dos tablas en una tengo una lista de periodos y en otra tengo datos pero no de todo los periodos (deseo combinar al periodo con cada nro de RUC y que se llene solo los periodos que tenga datos el resto q lo llene como NULL), Les muestro una imagen de lo que quiero . Uso TSQL. Tengo las tablas como en la imagen 1 e imagen 2 y lo  que deseo es la imagen 3.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select a.*,
    b.ruc,b.ESTADO
from #temp1 a
left join (
            select 
            SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,a.fecha_hasta,112),1,4) +
            SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,a.fecha_hasta,112),5,2) as PERIODO,
            a.*,
            b.Estado from db_ocg.khd.Hist_Estado_Lima a 
            left join db_ocg.khd.Estado b on
            a.cod_est = b.cod_est
            where 
            --RUC in ('10199770182') and
            SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,fecha_hasta,112),1,4) = '2019'
    ) as b
on a.PERIODO = b.PERIODO
order by 1
```

Comment: ¿Bienvenido a SOes Junior! ¿En qué parte del join estás atorado?

Comment: select a.*,
 b.ruc,b.ESTADO
from #temp1 a
left join (
   select 
   SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,a.fecha_hasta,112),1,4) +
   SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,a.fecha_hasta,112),5,2) as PERIODO,
   a.*,
   b.Estado from db_ocg.khd.Hist_Estado_Lima a 
   left join db_ocg.khd.Estado b on
   a.cod_est = b.cod_est
   where 
   RUC in ('10199770182') and
   SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,fecha_hasta,112),1,4) = '2019'
 ) as b
on a.PERIODO = b.PERIODO
order by 1

Comment: El problema es cuando quito el ruc del where no lo combina para todo los rucs solo lo hace cuando pongo un ruc en especifico, quiero que cree todo los periodos para todo los rucs no solo para uno

Comment: Intentaste cambiar tu left join por `inner join` o `right join`?

Comment: La consulta que muestras esta bien, y lo que dices al quitar el ruc en especifico, no tiene sentido.

Comment: Cuando utilizo el inner o el right hace lo mismo, lo q sucede es q en la consulta donde estoy haciendo el join lo q me devuelve es varios nro de ruc con varios periodos, varios rucs pueden tener el periodo 201901, 201902, 201903,.... hasta 201912, y la consulta es como si lo filtrara solo con los periodos que existen, no les aumenta los null x cada ruc, ese es el problema

Comment: Lo que muestran las imágenes son datos reales? como obtuviste los resultados de la tabla "imagen 3"? pregunto esto porque si lo que muestran las imágenes es toda la data, no hay manera de obtener nulls. Ayudaría mucho si publicaras una muestra mas amplia de tus datos.

Comment: Si son datos reales, pero ya lo pude solucionar lo q hice primero es crear una tabla con cada ruc y combinarlo con los periodos, y luego de eso hacer el join, la ercera imagen sale simplemente quitando el comentario del where q subi en la publicacion.